# What is red box, yellow box and green box testing?

Tags: testing, terminology

I can find many explanations on difference between black box and white box testing, but couldn't find any better explanation on Red box, Yellow box and Green box testing.

Can someone please explain these types of testing terms? Examples will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Red box testing is when you say "I'm sick of testing!" and go rent a DVD from a vending machine instead.

Comment: Yellow would be then to just speed up and skim through the testing (just what we do at yellow traffic light)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different colors of testing and techniques in Software Testing:

1. **White Box** = Unit and Integration testing
2. **Black Box** = The following techniques:

   - BVA (Boundary Value Analysis)
   - ECP (Equivalence Class Partitioning)
   - Decision Tables
   - STF (State  Transition flows)
   - Error Guessing
3. **Yellow Box** = Acceptance testing
4. **Green Box** = Release testing
5. **Gray Box** = Maintenance testing

Comment: Are there any references for this list or is this something your organization has defined?

Answer (score 2):

Red box testing is User Acceptance Testing.
Yellow Box testing is to test the Warning or Alert messages.

Answer (score 1):

Google has one result, several alternatives

http://www.testrepublic.com/forum/topics/define-red-box-testing-yellow

Answer (score 0):

Acceptance testing, often referred to as **Red-Box testing.**
Simply **yellow box testing** is checking against the warning 
messages. The system properly throwing the warning messages 
or not?

Answer (score 0):

**Red Box Testing:** Also referred as acceptance testing. in which user/client apply any technique like black box testing, white box testing and gray box testing to accept the project.

**Yellow Box Testing:** check against warning messages that weather the system throws the warning messages or not.

**Green Box Texting**: takes the external perspective of the test objective to derive the test cases.

Answer (score 0):

It is a testing done by the customer or end-user wherein they will use the software for real time business scenario for some period of time and check how well the software can handle the real time business work flow

Answer (score -1):

As per my experience, I found:

- Red Box Testing: When you are testing the application/product in Red area is known as Red Box Testing.
- Yellow Box Testing: When you are testing the application/product in Yellow garden area is known as Red Box Testing.
- Green Box Testing: The combination of front box testing and back box testing is known as Green Box testing.

Comment: Can you offer any references to these being used in this way?